# How to write simple_form for nested resources with a renamed path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a `Band` model and a `BandMember` model. My routes definition is

```
resources :bands do
  resources :band_members, as: :members, path: 'members'
end
```

Now I want to make a simple form for `BandMember` like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@band, @band_member] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

This throws an exception:

```
undefined method `band_band_member_path'
```

This would have worked if my model name was `Member` instead of `BandMember`. I do not wish to rename the model. Any ideas to get around this?

Comment: Remove @band and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `url` option of the `simple_form_for` method:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@band, @band_member], url: your_url_helper_path do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm. Thanks